# tensorflow gpu tests pass--but I don't have cuDNN installed

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

Windows10-pro, single RTX 2080 Ti.  I am new to Tensorflow.

I just installed tensorflow-gpu, version 2.1.0, python 3.7.7.  Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.105. Nothing self-compiled.  And I have not installed cuDNN, nor have I registered.  All installation is standard, nothing self-compiled.

The tensorflow.org documentation states that cuDNN is needed to use the GPU.  But my tests for GPU-usage seem to pass. For example,
`tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')` returns `[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]`.

It may appear that I should just install cuDNN and not lose any more sleep.  But I would still want to know if I were using the GPU so I would prefer a test that is capable of failing.

Is there a true test to see if an installation will use the GPU?

Comment: I followed [this](https://bleedai.com/installing-tensorflow-2-0-gpu-in-windows-setting-up-your-nvidia-gpu-for-opencv-dnn/) tutorial and tensorflow was working perfectly for me

Answer (score 0):

In NVIDIA GPU computing toolkit, one can verify the cuDNN installation,
On windows system,
Go to

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0\include\

open cudnn.h
```

To utilize the Tensorflow-GPU successfully, CUDA and cuDNN are required.
Some of the Tensorflow library such as `tf.keras.layers.GRU`([Keras GRU layers](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/GRU)) employs the capability of cuDNN.

Check these examples provided in [Tensorflow site](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu) for GPU utilization.